# Postgresql batch update with Spring. How to write a function with no return value

Tags: spring, postgresql, plpgsql, spring-jdbc

I am in the process of migrating from MySQL to PosgreSql and an have a slight problem with a proc/function I want to call in a batch update.

How can I perform an update on a Postgresql function when it always seems to return a value even if you declare the value to be void.

This is just a simple example to illustrate the problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_function(
  IN i_id bigint)
  RETURNS void AS $$
  DECLARE
    d_id bigint;
  BEGIN
    UPDATE test_table set id = '' where id = i_id;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I call this using a SpringTemplate.update() method it has the error "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected." 
If you call update and it returns a value it throws an error I understand that, so.

My question is, is there any way for a postgresql function to not return a value or will I need to find an alternative way to do the batch update? I should mention that the reason I want to do the update using a function is there is a number of tables being updated in the proc/function the above is just a simple explanation.

An alternative could for me to parse in an array of input values and loop over them.

Comment: Your postgres version and exact query you use to call this function?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.5 and I am calling with "select save_class_function(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Comment: What about `execute()` method?

Comment: Pavel, I am not sure, when I try execute I get the error that the stored procedure doesn't exist. I have written it as a function so perhaps that is the problem I need to change the function to a stored procedure but when I had a look at the documentation (not a detailed look) it seemed like functions were the stored procedures.

Comment: "Stored procedure" is synonymous with "function" in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it your problem is that PostgreSQL will add a row to the result set even though your function didn't return one.  A quick test showed that, in fact, these are returning a null from PostgreSQL.

What I do (and I realize this may not be the Spring way) is to have a function that does what I need it to do, and returns a useful value.  Then I take that value and use it for sanity checking purposes.  I might, for example, return the total number of rows updated (or perhaps the most recent version of the parent-most row) and hand that back to the application to use.

However, yes, you will need to find another way to do this.